# I want to load language before any UI is displayed with ui-router resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I use `angular-translate`. I want to load language before any UI is displayed. This is my code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YeyzCqnPJ6C2lF48RWD0?p=preview

when run this code error me

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areqp0=AdminCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

If you have experience about resolve a angular-translate language file, help me

Thanks

Comment: your plunker don't have angular-cookie file included due to which it give failed to instantiate module error. please fix that first

Comment: We fix it, my problem related to nested load language file. we define admin that has a `shared` lang keys and every child of admin has a spesific lang keys. when I refresh a child state, error me. I think AdminCtrl load after `shared` lang keys.